# What exactly IS a unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging

Same as title!

*EDIT: Almost exactly the same as, and would be contextually equal to [What is unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/)*

Comment: When I typed in the question, that sure didn't come up - but thank you for the rudeness.

Comment: You are right, the related question does not show up when you type that title. Nevertheless, closing duplicates is not rude on Stack Overflow. It is necessary and not to be taken personally.

Comment: Which is why I said "almost exactly the same as", because while the wording is different (causing it NOT to show up) the context of the question IS the same. We need to close duplicates to make sure questions aren't repeatedly answered as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste:

> Unit testing From Wikipedia, the free
>   encyclopedia   (Redirected from Unit
>   test) Jump to: navigation, search
>
> In computer programming, unit testing
>   is a method of testing that verifies
>   the individual units of source code
>   are working properly. A unit is the
>   smallest testable part of an
>   application. In procedural programming
>   a unit may be an individual program,
>   function, procedure, etc., while in
>   object-oriented programming, the
>   smallest unit is a method, which may
>   belong to a base/super class, abstract
>   class or derived/child class.
>
> Ideally, each test case is independent
>   from the others; Double objects like
>   stubs, mock or fake objects[1] as well
>   as test harnesses can be used to
>   assist testing a module in isolation.
>   Unit testing is typically done by
>   software developers to ensure that the
>   code other developers have written
>   meets software requirements and
>   behaves as the developer intended.