# What is unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/what-is-unit-testing)

What is unit testing and unit testing libraries like xUnit? I understand it's testing specific code, so what's the difference between this and just opening a new project and test this specific code?