# Testing the application manually

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database, testing

I want to test my application manually.
As am new to testing, can anyone suggest me, what are the things to be taken care when testing the application manually?

With Regards

Shreya

Comment: Well, it's really going to depend on the specifics of your application, however, if you are new to testing, I would recommend doing some reading on testing in general; here's a link to help you get started but a web search on things like 'how to test' or 'testing sql applications' will probably give you plenty to digest. http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/how-to-write-effective-test-cases-test-cases-procedures-and-definitions/

Comment: What are you searching for? _"Testing"_ as in _debugging_, or as in _unit testing_?

Comment: you're welcome; I hope find what you are looking for!

Comment: @Leito: Unit Testing. Actually i have developed an Online Shopping application.

Comment: also, there's a really good site on automated unit testing that I've been reading through for a while now that might be of interest to you: http://xunitpatterns.com/

Comment: @shelley: Surely i wil go through it..

Answer (score 2):

Also, actively try to break it. Start messing about. Enter bogus values, long pieces of text, etc into input fields. Double click on buttons or links. If there's a workflow to be followed, try to do stuff that doesn't follow the normal workflow.

EDIT: google for stuff like 'QA checklist' or 'software QA checklist' and you'll find some inspiration. They can [get](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/Software-Testing-Check-List/) [quite](http://www.testinggeek.com/web-application-functional-testing-checklist) [extensive](http://bazman.tripod.com/).

Answer (score 0):

When testing manually, you would simply use your application. Not quite sure what else you mean. If you implement a feature, try to use every single part of that feature, including every single part of anything it might interact with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch a bug, you have to think like a bug. Forget about the intent of your application, and what it is supposed to do and what a user was supposed to do, and take it like a game: "given all I know of this application, how fast can I get it to crash"? Also look at use cases or scenarios, and for each step, try to imagine paths that are not the happy path. What preconditions could not be satisfied, and how could you get there?

It probably doesn't really qualify as "manual", but a tool like [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) is excellent at helping you figure out what inputs could possibly get methods out of whack.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Peter wrote:

- resize the window to unlikely sizes (very small/ very big/very wide but with a small height)
- move the window frantically around and see if this affects the look & feel
- try to use the application with a touchpad( can be found on laptops) or those red sticks in the middle of the keybaord that you will find on some laptops

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform unit testing, you might want to check out [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/).
Also, read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/what-is-unit-testing) if you're new at unit testing.