# How to execute error checking on multiple PHP files simultaneously?

Tags: php, svn, svn-checkout, error-checking

I have an svn server that I checkout the repository in my computer.

The main repositiry has about 2k files

- 3rd party
- generic code classes
- custom classes

I have made changes to lots of files (mainly php) and I want to make sure they are all valid before I commit.

```
svn commit -m "i fix the bug #293"
```

How can I check all the files at once to make sure they are valid and no php errors so I dont have to manually check all these files.

Comment: Do you mean you modified the code without being able to run it on your developer machine? Bad practice....

Comment: Run your [Unit Tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/what-is-unit-testing) before commiting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This bash oneliner will the modified php files and filter the ones that have no syntax errors:

```
for i in $(svn status | grep -v ^? | grep php | awk '{print $2}') ; do php -l $i ; done | grep 'Parse error'
```

Comment: `for i in $(svn status|grep -v ^?|grep php|awk '{print $2}') ; do php -l $i ; done | grep 'Parse error'`