# Why does std::getline(cin, Number) give a "No matching function for call" error?

Tags: c++

I wrote a program so the user inputs a number and the program outputs its binary representation.

I get this error:

> No matching function for call to `getline(std::istream&, unsigned int&)'

How can I solve this?

Also, it outputs:

```
0
0
0
0
```

...when it should output the right value for the input.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Number;
    cin >> Number;
    bool Binary[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
        Binary[(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1) - i] = Number & (1 << i);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
        std::cout << Binary[i] << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: using namespace std; and then why use std::cout and std::endl

Comment: you should indent your code for readbility...

Comment: and why getline? cant you use std::cin>>number

Comment: How did you get incorrect output when it doesn't *compile*?

Answer (score 11):

The `getline()` function takes an `istream` and a *`string`*, not an integer. So:

```
string sNumber;
getline(cin, sNumber);
// now convert sNumber to an unsigned int
```

Answer (score 2):

[**`std::getline()`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) gets a *line* into a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) variable. You'll need to convert it to an `unsigned int` yourself. The usual way is to use a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) instance like so:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main ()
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    unsigned int number = 0U;

    if (!(iss >> number))
    {
        // Handle error
    }
    else
    {   // Put your binary conversion logic in a function!
        std::cout << to_binary(number) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Tip**: Indentation can greatly improve the readability and maintainability of your code.

Putting your binary conversion logic into a function will make it easier to test (think [**"unit-test"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/what-is-unit-testing)) and to reuse, like this:

```
// I've left this logic untouched other than to indent it and to introduce
// braces. It needs to be fixed. Declare before main().

std::string to_binary(unsigned int Number)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    bool Binary[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
    {
        Binary[(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1) - i] = Number & (1 << i);
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        oss << Binary[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return oss.str();
}
```

I've left correcting your binary conversion logic as an exercise as this looks like homework.

Comment: @Joriek: It (your compiler) would give you an error if you had not extracted the function `to_binary()`. I'be updated my answer to clarify what that may look like.

Answer (score 1):

`getline` can only be used to read in a complete line as a string. If you want to read in a number, use `operator>>`.

Example:

```
int number;
std::cin >> number;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int Number;
std::cin >> number;
```

and why you cant use getline(). [Read this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)!!

Answer (score 0):

The following are the valid signatures of getline:

```
istream& getline(char*, int, char = '\n');
istream& getline(signed char*, int, char = '\n');
istream& getline(unsigned char*, int, char = '\n');
```

You are not using any of them

Comment: that is istream::getline not free-function getline

Answer (score -1):

Change `getline(cin, Number)` to `cin >> Number`