# Is there a way to test the code changes in a war file without running maven build?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm currently working on a maven project which has 5 modules. As part of bug fixes, I need to make some small changes in a java file and in order to get those changes refelected, I run a maven build(which is pretty time consuming) and get it deployed in Tomcat.

Is there a way to test my changes without running a maven build? Please advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/what-is-unit-testing)

Answer (score 0):

War file always use .class file

you can put your compiled .class file into folder used by tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Eclipse IDE you can do it.

```
Right Click Project -> Export -> WarfileName , Destination -> Finish
```